# How can i get the saved image's link?

Tags: node.js, base64

I'm a beginner in `nodeJS` . I'm trying to store an `image` by converting `base64` string to image in folder ,the image is being saved properly but when I'm trying to access that image by `"localhost:8080/image.jpg"` it's not showing the image.

My Code is:

```
fs.writeFile('image.jpg',base64 string, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
     console.log('File created');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by using following code.After making the directory static now it can be accessed through "localhost:8080/image.jpg"

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you serve the image through a server? If not localhost will not work. You can use the file protocol to get this to display in the browser. You can go to a url like:

`file://[path to file]/image.jpg`

Comment: I want the link not only to view the image but also to store that link into the database so how can I get a link for that purpose